# Are windows services secrets in the registry safe?

Tags: windows, password-management, windows-services

Are windows services registry keys stored securely - encrypted on the disk, protected by an ACL by default or similar?

The key being in `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\{SERVICE_NAME}` or similar.

As an example, say I've got a java application which runs on windows as a service and it needs environment specific passwords / passphrases on startup, is it safe to put these in the registry as startup parameters on the service?

My guess is no, they are cleartext on the disk somewhere deep in the bowels of `c:\windows` and that ACLs dont apply to normal registry keys, but I can't really find any info one way or the other..

Follow up question - what's a good approach for passing secrets to a service when it starts?

Comment: What's the definition of "safe"? From whom are you trying to keep these secrets?

Comment: kept away from someone who shouldn't be able to read them. Other users on the same machine (non-admin at least), other processes running on it that sort of thing.

Comment: Encrypted, No, some are protected by ACL's. It is safe from nothing, as stated by harrymc, it can be mounted under linux, then the ACL's mean nothing. Malware loves the Windows registry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The registry cannot be accessed by non-admins, so registry secrets are safe from
them.

The `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM` registry hive is physically located in the file
`C:\Windows\System32\config\SYSTEM` and cannot be accessed when Windows is running.
A user can always boot Linux and mount the file, but someone with that level
of knowledge can in any case never be blocked if he gets physical access to the
computer.

A malevolent system service can do anything at all on the computer, so no point
in keeping secrets from it.

The only possible protection is encrypting the data, but this also cannot
block someone who has the ability to disassemble your program and extract
the algorithm.

There are no sure ways of protecting data. All you can hope to do is make it
too difficult for anybody not having a certain level of knowledge, or who is not
willing to personally invest the required time.